# Pulumi is creating an azure resource group with a different name

Tags: azure, pulumi

Why Pulumi is not creating a resource group with the name I gave?

Here is my small script

```js
const azure = require("@pulumi/azure")

const resourceGroupName = new azure.core.ResourceGroup("test-pulumi", {
    location: "francecentral",
});
```

The name of the resource group is: test-pulumi83d54581

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` parameter that you give is your component's name, not the full name of the resource to be created. By default, Pulumi appends a suffix to all names to avoid name collision e.g. across multiple stacks.

To specify the name explicitly, pass it as options parameter:

```js
const resourceGroupName = new azure.core.ResourceGroup("test-pulumi", {
    name: "test-pulumi",
    location: "francecentral",
});
```

That's a bit verbose, and we might get an option to disable name suffixes - see [this issue](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi/issues/1518) for progress.